# What is "sun up" in the shopping situation?

Tags: meaning

Probably, I heard it wrong. When I bought a candle in the glass cup, at the cashier, a lady asked me "do you need sun up?". But I couldn't understand what she was trying to say. Could you tell me what this is?

Probably it was "sum up". But I still don't get this. I only bought one candle by the credit card...

Comment: [**SumUp**](https://sumup.co.uk/) is a card payment terminal used by small retailers. "Do you need SumUp?" – *"Are you paying by card?"*

Comment: Thank you so much! This is it! I learned something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SumUp](https://sumup.co.uk/) is a card payment terminal used by small retailers. "Do you need SumUp?" – *"Are you paying by card?"*

<sup><sup>Credit: [Weather Vane](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507765/what-is-sun-up-in-the-shopping-situation#comment1229776_507765)</sup></sup>